# When should a Device-Watchdog-Request be sent?

Tags: diameter-protocol

[RFC6733](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6733#section-5.5.3)

Options:

1. always by timeout
2. when there is no messaging
3. when there is an error from the diameter-server

It is not clear from the RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each peer should send WDR (both client and server) every X seconds.
Usually there is a configuration to adjust how much time to wait between WDRs.
(It does not have to be the same time in the client and in the server)